# FPDF error sending output to browser

Tags: php, fpdf

I am getting this error message:

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

when I launch the following code; do you know why? can you help me?

```
$i = 0;
while ($i <= $y)
{
  $namefilepdf=$x_labelname.$i.'.pdf';
  $pdf=new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage($x_lay,$x_dimpag);
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial');           

  if (isset($x_toprint1))
    if ($x_toprint1=='on')
        if (isset($x_progressive1))
        {
          if ($x_progressive1=='on')
          {
            $pdf->SetFontSize($x_font1);
            $pdf->Text($x_coordx1,$x_coordy1,$x_val1+$i);
          }
        }
        else
        {
            $pdf->SetFontSize($x_font1);
            $pdf->Text($x_coordx1,$x_coordy1,$x_valore1);
        }
  $pdf->Output($namefilepdf,'D');
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: What will you see when commenting line `$pdf->Output($namefilepdf,'D');` ? A blank screen?

Answer (score 2):

For FPDF to work, there can't be *any* other output. Things like `echo` statements elsewhere in your PHP file, anything (including spaces) before or after your `<?php ?>` tags, etc. will cause that error message.

I suspect that somewhere else in your PHP file, there's probably some non-FPDF output that's causing you to see that error.

Answer (score 1):

it's beacuse somewhere in your code before outputing you pdf object you have already done some `echo` or `var_dump` or any other output metod.
when outputing data using `header` you can not send anything else before the `header` statement to the standard output

Comment: specificaly i would assume you can not output more than 1 file at `$pdf->Output($namefilepdf,'D');` -> the first file can pass but looping into another will give error. how could you otherwise download more than 1 file with visiting just 1 weblink?

Answer (score 1):

Use output buffering here :-

Before send to output clean the output buffer using `ob_clean();`.

```
 ob_clean();//add this line 
 $pdf->Output($namefilepdf,'D');
```

Please refer this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) to know about `ob_clean();`