# update php version pdf error

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I try to update the version of php on my server from 5.3 to 5.5.
I have one last bug with pdf.
When I try to print a pdf (the same pdf that works in 5.3), the pdf doesn't open on the screen. I have this error: Invalid XRef stream header.
The response type is already change in my php file to this 'application/pdf'.
I am using fpdf to generate my pdf.
Have you an idea of the problem to help me.

Comment: You most likely got some PHP errors (deprecated mysql_* function use, undefined vars), outputted before the PDF generation. download the PDF and open it with a text,HEX editor or such to see the errors

Comment: I have a lot of Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "112" in hex string
pdf.worker.js (ligne 234)
<système>
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "114" in hex string
pdf.worker.js (ligne 234)
<système>
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "108" in hex string
pdf.worker.js (ligne 234)
<système>
2
Warning: Ignoring invalid character "115" in hex string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line "ob_end_clean();" before $pdf->Output(); and also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137072/fpdf-error-sending-output-to-browser)